# Interop - save UTF-8 .csv to .xlsx

Tags: vb.net, interop, excel-interop

Using Excel.Interop I want to open a .txt or .csv file and save it as an excel file. Most of the times this simple code works:

```
Dim Exl As New Excel.Application()
Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook = Exl.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyFile.txt", Format:=4)
wb1.SaveAs("C:\MyFile.xlsx", FileFormat:=Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook)
wb1.Close()
Exl.Quit()
```

However sometimes the .txt/.csv that is being converted contains special characters like ü, ä or ö - and in these cases these characters are replaced by other characters in the resulting excel file. 
The problem seems to be that the input files are UTF-8 encoded. So I tried to change the second line to

```
Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook = Exl.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyFile.txt", Format:=4, Origin:=61005)
```

which doesn't work either.

Another option that I came across was to simply use `OpenText` instead of `Open`, however now I get an exception:

```
    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbooks
    wb1.OpenText("C:\MyFile.txt")
    Exl.wb1.SaveAs("C:\MyFile.xlsx", FileFormat:=Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook)
    wb1.Close()
    Exl.Quit()
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: If you have the text file initially, you could (if needed) write a small code to open and read the contents (`system.io.File.ReadAllLines("c:\blah.txt"`) and check the contents to see if it contains any of those characters? What you do with that I'm not sure, would you be happy removing them at all?

Comment: no, sadly I need them exactly the way they are in the csv in the excel....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Origin` parameter of the [Workbooks.Open Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel) must be a value from the XlPlatform enumeration;

```
 Name          Value               Description  
 xlMacintosh     1                 Macintosh  
 xlMSDOS         3                 MS-DOS 
 xlWindows       2                 Microsoft Windows
```

Your code:

```
wb1 As Excel.Workbook = Exl.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyFile.txt", Format:=4, Origin:=61005)
```

is trying to specify a [code page identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx).  This is supported by the `Origin` parameter of the [Workbooks.OpenText Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel).  Additionally, you have a transcription error in the identifier value; it should be 65001 not 61005.

Here is an example using then `OpenText` method.

```
Sub Example()
    Const UTF8CodePage As Int32 = 65001
    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    app.Visible = True
    Dim filePath As String = "F:\TestUTF_8Quoted.txt"
    Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(filePath)
    app.Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:=filePath, Semicolon:=True, Origin:=UTF8CodePage, TextQualifier:=Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote)
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Item(fi.Name)
    wb.Close(False)
    app.Quit()
End Sub
```

Comment: thx, that works - so the Origin Parameter in the .Open method only seems to refer to the operating system.